# Displaying Model content on page and "check for null", MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display the string content of my model in a .cshtml file in an MVC application. I am trying to simply display the content of Model.SomeString on page:

```
<p> @(Model.SomeString == null ? "Empty String" : Model.SomeString ) </p>
```

This gives the following error:

> NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."

How do I display content of my model on page? I am trying to implement my own helpers, and therefore do not use the ones included in mvc. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your model is probably `null`. Are you passing it to the view from the controller? There's no relevant code snippet, so right now it's guesswork...

Comment: You were entirely right, my model was null. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're passing an instance of your model to the view.

In your controller:

```
MyModel myModelInstance = new MyModel();

return View(myModelInstance);
```

This should obviously be the same object as the one you're referencing in your view file:

```
@model MyModel
```

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project!